# VBA code to hide blank rows, hide another set of rows with data in it, and manipulate cell in different spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with three different spreadsheets (tabs). I need to create a macro button in the first spreadsheet that when clicked on, it will hide any blank rows in rows 18-33 and hide rows 53-110. Unlike rows 18-33, rows 53-110 will always have words written in them. This workbook is used for project budgets and only one project (project A) doesn't need the information located in rows 53-110. In addition to these two parameters for the button, I also need the macro button to set cell G26 on the third spreadsheet (which is labeled Third-Party) to 10%. Cell G26 in the Third-Party tab has a drop down menu consisting of 0%, 5%, 10%, and 15% (I unchecked the show error alert so that users can enter a different percentage if necessary). For all other projects besides Project A, this cell needs to be set to 10% which is why I need the button to also change cell G26 on the third tab from 10% to 0% (again, strictly for Project A which this macro button is to be created for).

I have tried using the macro codes below. I was able to copy and paste a macro button from a previous workbook and assign these codes to them so don't need help creating another button; can simply copy and paste one from a previous template and then assign the new Project A macro codes to it. To explain further, every project budget needs a macro button to hide all blank rows and another macro button to unhide all blank rows. Since every project is different, there isn't a universal number of rows needed; these buttons are to make it easier for future users to make the project budget template presentable. As of now, I have one button to hide all blank cells in this range (rows 18->33) and another button to unhide all blank cells in said range. My question is in regard to creating a third button for a special project (Project A). Each of the three tabs have the hide and unhide buttons. I need a third macro button with the three parameters I mentioned above to be located in the first tab which will only be used for Project A.

```
Sub HideRows()
    Dim r As Range, c As Range
    Set r = Range("A18:A33")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each c In r
        If Len(c.Text) = 0 Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub UnhideRows()
    'To Hide Rows 18 to 33
    Rows("18:33").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    'To UnHide Rows 18 to 33
    Rows("18:33").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

The codes above only hide blank rows between rows 18->33 in the first spreadsheet. I'm not sure how to hide more than one set of blank rows let alone what to do when one set needs blank cells hidden but the other set needs information hidden nor how to create a code to manipulate a cell in a different tab at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out myself and wanted to share for anyone who also has this issue.

```
Sub UndoGoogleTemplate()
'First Macro
Call UnhideTermsAndConditions
'Second Macro
Call ManagementFeeBackTo5
End Sub

Sub UnhideTermsAndConditions()
Range("53:110").Rows.Hidden = False
End Sub

Sub ManagementFeeBackTo5()
Sheets("THIRD-PARTY").Range("d26").Value = 0.05
End Sub
```

I used a different button for hiding blank rows which is why that third macro isn't included.